# Можно ли сказать "индивидуальное последствие данного явления"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "индивидуальное последствие данного явления" в значении, что какое-то конкретное последствие относится к какому-то конкретному явлению?
Если слово "индивидуальное" в этом случае не подходит, то на каким другим аналогичным словом  его можно заменить?

Answer (score 0):

**Одно из**/**отдельное** (но НЕ индивидуальное) последствие магнитной бури - это запись исправно работающих датчиков в зоне воздействия бури.
Головную боль у некоторых индивидуумов (людей) можно (но не нужно) назвать индивидуальным последствием магнитной бури.
Индивидуальные последствия падения человека с высоты своего роста на пол - это синяки у молодых и переломы у стариков и больных остеопорозом.
Такое употребление ПМСМ верное.
Итого:
Индивидуальным последствием явления можно что-то называть при выполнении следующих условий:

1. Явление затрагивает только совокупность однотипных объектов и только ее.
2. Объекты должны быть разнокачественные.
3. Последствия воздействия явления должны быть разными в зависимости от разнокачественности объектов.